# How to exit SSH of vagrant in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, vagrant

Following the README in [this repository](https://github.com/honza/django-chef), I am supposed to secure shell my way into a virtual machine I've created, but once I've done so, how do I get out?

Here are the instructions:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/honza/django-chef.git
$ cd django-chef
# add yourself to the "users" array in the Vagrantfile
$ sudo echo "127.0.0.1 example.example.com" >> /etc/hosts
$ vagrant up
$ fab vagrant:honza bootstrap  # replace with your name
$ vagrant ssh    # OK, cool
$ run            # I'm trapped!
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming the `run` command stays running on the foreground, you can most probably end it with `CTRL+C`. Then the shell (and SSH) session can be terminated with `exit` or `CTRL+D`.

Comment: I'm using Cmder in windows 10, `exit` and `CTRL+D` worked for me, but `CTRL+C` didn't work.

Comment: Same for me. `exit` seems to be the best answer here.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ssh to the machine you can do following:

```
vagrant ssh
```

or

```
homestead ssh
```

If you are in the machine you can run the command `exit` to get out of it.

Comment: Note that `homestead ssh` is a common alias that's specific to the homestead Vagrant box for Laravel development. Only `vagrant ssh` should work for this question.